# 1 form, 1 route, 2 classes

Tags: javascript, html, ktor

Im trying to create fullstack app for sorting warehouse documents. But I face some logic barrier.
 
I want to create:
**Front** that will be designed like document page, header with all document details and body with ordered positions. 
**Back** that will handle document(header, bodies) from single route and using two different models(headerModel, bodyModel) will insert data to db.

I was thinking did its possible to sort it using HTML form, that will convert all data from page to below example JSON, receive it on backend, parse it to model and insert.
Example JSON:

```
{header{var:val,var:val,var:val},
body1{var:val,var,val},
body2{var:val,var:val}}
```

Did it have sense to do it in this way? Im not very experience with programming and its have logic sense for me as theory. I will be very thankful for any tips or idea about how to design that process.

Im using ktor as backend and front end will be created in Kotlin/JS with wrappers for React.

Comment: Could you please describe the use cases of your application in more detail? If you use React then you most likely have all data, required to create or update a document, in a state, that you can transform to JSON and send to a server.

Comment: It will be small Warehouse management system, user will can do crud operarions on documents and confirm quantity of items. So user will create document, process, then confirm quantity line by line, update document and close document

Answer (score 0):

To render some document you fetch data from the server, convert it, and make your React components use it. When changes in a document are needed you take the data from a state of your components or a store, e.g Redux, convert it to a JSON-like object and send it to the server.

So basically you need to write a few converters from/to JSON in Kotlin/JS.